How to correctly perform inverse Fourier transform when input length is greater than output length?
Suppose I have $N$ length input sequence and need to inverse transform the input to length $K$ where $K<N$? Is possible at all?

It's certainly possible, but what you need specifically determines how to go about doing it. Do you need the first $K$ samples of an $N$ length sequence? Or do you need a downsampled version of the $N$ length sequence?

Its down sampled version. Specifically its the part of fast-spherical filter. I have managed to make it work the interpolation but filtering is not working properly.

The $N$ samples on the grid from in level $L$ needs to be filtered to fit into $K$ samples of the grid in level $L+1$.

To invert a shorter version of your frequency domain signal to the time domain, discard the necessary number of high frequencies to reduce the length from N to K. If K is an even number, the highest frequency will be the Nyquist frequency, so you must set its imaginary component to zero (since phase information cannot be determined at the Nyquist frequency). Finally, transform to the time domain.
